# Find $\left| T \right|$ where is certain linear transformation from $C\left[ a,b\right]$ to $\Bbb R$ ...

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to get some help or hints with the following problem ...

Let $C\left[ a,b \right]$ is the set of all real valued functions defined on $[a,b]$ and if $f \in C\left[ a,b \right]$, define $\left| f \right|=\sup \{ \left| f(x) \right| : x \in [a,b]\}$. Let $g_0 \in C\left[ a,b \right]$ fixed and let $T:C\left[ a,b \right] \to \Bbb R$ be given by the correspondence $f \mapsto \int_a^b{f(t)g_0(t)dt}$. Show that $T$ is linear and continuous. Find $\left| T \right|$, where $$|T|=\sup_{f\not\equiv 0} \frac{|T(f)|}{|f|}$$

---

**What I've done:**

It is easy to see that $T$ is linear since the integral is a linear functional on $[a,b]$. Since
$$ |T(f)|=\int_a^b{f(t)g_0(t)dt} \leq \int_a^b{|f(t)g_0(t)|dt} $$
and $|f(t)| \leq |f|$ for all $t\in [a,b]$, it follows that 
$$ |T| \leq \left( \int_a^b{|g_0(t)|dt} \right)|f| $$
for all $f\in C\left[ a,b\right]$. Whence $T$ is continuous. Also, we conclude 
$$ |T| \leq \int_a^b{|g_0(t)|dt} $$

**The real question:**

I've been trying to prove that $|T|=\int_a^b{|g_0(t)|dt}$ but got nothing interesting. I think the answer can be obtained using **Cauchy-Schwartz inequality** since 
$$ \langle f,g \rangle =\int_a^b{f(t)g(t)dt} $$
is an inner product on $C\left[ a,b\right]$. The equality holds if and only if $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent.

If we find $f_0\in C\left[ a,b \right]$ such that $|T(f_0)|=\int_a^b{|g_0(t)|dt}$, we win, but... does such $f_0$ exist? Is there any other way to prove $|T|=\int_a^b{|g_0(t)|dt}$ ?

Any help or hints are higly appreciated.